# Shouldn't asm.js be slow if it has to manage the heap itself?

Tags: javascript, performance, heap-memory, emscripten, asm.js

So, I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.

According to the asm.js spec, an asm.js module is given a single large typed array that acts as the heap.  Why is it set up this way?  Doesn't that slow things down, because the asm.js module itself has to keep track of the heap?

I'm asking because I had concerns about this when I first saw the spec but wasn't sure if I was missing something, but then found my emscripten-compiled code, which is very heavy on heap allocation/deallocation all the time, to be 10-20 times slower than native rather than the 1.5-2x slower that seems to be seen in all the benchmarks, with asm.js code being slightly *slower* than normal JS.

Comment: What code did you use to compare? How did you test? What "native" code?

Comment: Neural network training/evaluation C++ code.  I set the iterations to very high and `time`d it.  Each time a new generation of nets is created, the best of the old generation (which is mostly thrown away) is selected, copied, and modified slightly, hence lots of heap allocation and deallocation.

Comment: Benchmarking Javascript can be ... misleading at times, based upon the benchmarking process.  Many benchmark programs create the function each loop, though denying the JIT a chance to be effective.

Comment: The iterations are from within the actual program's JS, which is all one giant program, rather than some benchmarking utility.  The whole program itself takes 10x longer to run from node.js (AKA, the V8 engine).

Comment: Ah, now I understand, you mean "native C++ application" not "native javascript code". The problem is that asm does not know "objects" or "structs" or whatever, so there cannot be "native" garbage collection by the engine.

Comment: I don't think asm.js would need to know what structs are or even what garbage collection is in order to support heap memory managed by the actual MMU instead of asm.js.

Comment: You may try to use duetto (https://github.com/leaningtech/duetto-wiki/wiki), which is an alternative, open source, C++ to JavaScript compiler designed to use native browser capabilities, including JavaScript objects and the JavaScript heap. Full disclosure, I am one of Duetto authors.